# Update sales_flat_order_item table in Magento

Tags: mysql, database, magento, magento-1.9

I've a scenario in which I need to update sales_flat_order_item table after creation of order. I am using following code:

```
$combine_array = Array
(
    [22500] => 257
    [4500] => 258
)

foreach ($combine_array as $item=>$key)
                {
                    $data = array('discount_amount'=> $item);
                    $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($key)->addData($data);
                    try{
                        $orderModel->setItemId($key)->save();
                    }catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        echo $e->getMessage();  
                    }
                }
```

But this code is not working. Kindly suggest how to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same code and it is updating the data perfectly. Below is my code:-

```
$combine_array = array(225010 => 108, 45010 => 109);

foreach ($combine_array as $item => $key) {
    $data = array('discount_amount' => $item);
    $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($key)->addData($data);
    try {
        $orderModel->setItemId($key)->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi arushi, you were correct, the same code is working. In my case, i was updating invoice also, that is why it was crewating issues.